# Why doesn't webservice work manually?

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I have webservice that has more than one method. I use firefox soaclient plugin for test them. All methods work properly. These are normal until now. I wrote library on android for call these .net webservice. I have methods, first one prepares envelop, the other one calls method. All methods except one work with these way. I get prepared envelop from my lib for method that doesn't work and use this envelope on firefox soap client, it returns me response in correct way. My own method that calls web service doesn't work wrong, just return empty result. What could be the error?

[image]

```
private void createEnvelope() {
    // Her bir parametrenin kalıbı
    String params = "<%s>%s</%s>";
    // Her parametre kalıbına değer atandığında geçici olarak tutulan string
    String paramsTemp = "";
    // Hazırlanan tüm parametrelerin tutulduğu değişken
    String paramsAll = "";

    // Parametreler ekleniyor
    for (int i = 0; i < parameterKeys.size(); i++) {
        paramsTemp = String.format(params, parameterKeys.get(i),
                parameterValues.get(i), parameterKeys.get(i));
        paramsAll += paramsTemp;
    }

    // soap mesajını hazılıyoruz
    String soapTemplate = "<?xml version=\"%s\" encoding=\"%s\"?>"
            + "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
            + "<soap:Body>" + "<%s xmlns=\"%s\">" + "%s" + "</%s>"
            + "</soap:Body>" + "</soap:Envelope>";
    envelope = String.format(soapTemplate, version, charEncoding,
            methodName, namespace, paramsAll, methodName);
    Logger.log("request:" + envelope);
}


public String callWebService() {

    createEnvelope();
    // request parameters
    HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, connectionTimeOut);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, soTimeOut);

    // set parameter
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpClient.getParams(), true);

    // POST the envelope
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    // add headers
    httppost.setHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);

    try {

        // the entity holds the request
        HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(envelope);
        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        // Response handler
        ResponseHandler<String> rh = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
            // invoked when client receives response
            public String handleResponse(HttpResponse responseTemp)
                    throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

                // get response entity
                HttpEntity entity = responseTemp.getEntity();
                StatusLine statusLine = responseTemp.getStatusLine();

                // read the response as byte array
                StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
                byte[] b = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);

                // write the response byte array to a string buffer
                out.append(new String(b, 0, b.length));
                return out.toString();
            }
        };

        response = httpClient.execute(httppost, rh);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Soap Service Exception:", e.toString());
    }

    // close the connection
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    return response;
}
```

EDIT

Request template on logcat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <Method_Name xmlns="url">
         <param1>12345</param1>
         <param2>ügıtç</param2>
         <param3>qwert</param3>
      </Method_Name>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

response template on logcat

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <Method_Name_Response xmlns="url">
         <Method_Name_Result>
            <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
               <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                  <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="Temp">
                           <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                 <xs:element name="response1" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
                                 <xs:element name="response2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                           </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                     </xs:choice>
                  </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" />
         </Method_Name_Result>
      </Method_Name_Response>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

response template on firefox  plugin with  same envelope

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <Method_Name_Response xmlns="url">
         <Method_Name_Result>
            <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
               <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                  <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="Temp">
                           <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                 <xs:element name="response1" type="xs:long" minOccurs="0" />
                                 <xs:element name="response2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                           </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                     </xs:choice>
                  </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
               <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                  <Temp diffgr:id="Temp1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                     <response1>123456789</response1>
                     <response2>Android</response2>
                  </Temp>
               </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
          </Method_Name_Result>
      </Method_Name_Response>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Post your `logcat` and if possible `wireshark` dump.

Comment: I edit my question with template results. Because of privacy of information I couldn't share original results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem, Turkish characters causes the error. When I use "ü" it causes error, when I don't use it, it works perfect.