# How to use Turkish character while calling webservice?

Tags: android, web-services, utf-8

I develop my own soap web service methods on android. But when I use Turkish characters, some problems causes. Webservice returns empty response. What should I do? You can view my function here [Why doesn't webservice work manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080334/why-doesnt-webservice-work-manually)

I also use

```
charEncoding = "utf-8";
version = "1.0";
contentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I use "iso-8859-9" char encoding instead of "utf-8" and now it works perfect.